# php: preg_match is not greedy?

Tags: php, preg-match

In php, I have the following situation:

```
$Text = "eb 6; 1 cor 4";
$Regex1 = '((eb 6(; 1)?|1 cor 4)(; )?)+';
$Regex2 = '((eb 6|1 cor 4)(; )?)+';

$Match1 = preg_match("/$Regex1/", $Text, $ArrayMatches1); 
$Match2 = preg_match("/$Regex2/", $Text, $ArrayMatches2);
```

`$Regex2` matches the whole variable: `eb 6; 1 cor 4`

`$Regex1` ends matching `eb 6; 1`.

Now, PCRE's are supposed to be greedy; since `$Regex2` is equivalent to `$Regex1` with `(; 1)` used 0 times, I'd expect `$Regex1` to return the longest possible match, while it doesn't happen: it seems that *the quantifiers* are greedy, but *the whole pcre* isn't greedy.

Am I missing something or is this a php bug?

Comment: did you try it with the x modifier?

Comment: Do you ask for an explanation of the two regex difference?

Comment: the x modifier doesn't solve.

Comment: Note that `(; )?` is not the same as `(; 1)?`. If you use `$Regex1 = '((eb 6(; )?|1 cor 4)(; )?)+';`, see https://regex101.com/r/CaU2lm/3, it will behave as the second regex.

Comment: I'm not trying to build a pcre that matches the whole variable, I'm trying to understand why I don't get the whole variable with $Regex1 too, in the assumptions that pcre's are greedy

Comment: You are mistaken, PCRE cannot be "greedy" or not, only quantifiers can be greedy or lazy. And you just made a typo in the first regex, that is all.

Comment: So, was that `1` a typo? Or what was your intention?

Comment: no it wasn't a typo,  I was trying to understand why I don't get the whole variable with $Regex1 too, in the assumptions that pcre's are greedy, but you have answered me: "PCRE cannot be "greedy" or not, only quantifiers can be greedy or lazy". Thank you